# biblatex-chicago with option authordate does not work anymore

Tags: biblatex, chicago-style

sorry if I just got something stupidly wrong, but I encountered a serious problem with the biblatex-chicago package.... Have to say: I just updated to the most recent MacTex version and this might be the reason, but I cannot find anything...

thats my preamble (that worked perfectly fine 2 weeks ago!)

```
\documentclass[10pt,oneside,a4paper]{scrartcl}


\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}

\clubpenalty=10000
\widowpenalty=10000
\displaywidowpenalty=10000

% ********************************BIBLATEX**************************
\usepackage[language=german,isbn=false,backend=bibtexu,authordate,babel=other]{biblatex-chicago}

\bibliography{/Users/moritzklenk/Documents/ZOTERO/EXPORTS/MyLibrary.bib}

% *************************************************************************
```

but just of now it gives my this error:

```
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.cfg)))
/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex-chicago/biblatex-chicago.sty:92: Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \global 
l.92 \csuse{cms@\cms@style}
```

If I get rid of the "authordate" option everything is just fine (except it is not using the author-date option for inline references, of course). What is wrong here?

All help is very much appreciated!!! Little bit desperate here...

Comment: One guess: The latest release of biblatex-chicago requires biber for the author-date styles. So try loading the package with `backend=biber`.

Comment: thanks! that solved the problem... I forgot to change the Bibtex engine in Texshop.... however, now I got like a million new problems... biber compiling brings up thousands of junk characters...


WARN - BibTeX subsystem: /var/folders/9z/9ps6l7cx17s7kfgfw613sp000000gn/T/636OgTs8WC/MyLibrary2.bib_67504.utf8, line 30916, warning: 1 characters of junk seen at toplevel
WARN - BibTeX subsystem: substring 3, warning: empty substring
WARN - BibTeX subsystem: substring 3, warning: empty substring
WARN - BibTeX subsystem: substring 3, warning: empty substring

Comment: First, remove all auxiliary files: `biber` and `bibtex` expect and require different things; second, look at your warnings: `biber` is very verbose and very helpful in pinpointing errors and/or suspect cruft in your `.bib` file.  E.g., it sounds as though you have a bunch of empty fields in your bibliography (possibly due to crossref-related reasons) --- something like `subtitle = {},`.  (Hard to say from here, though.) Third, watch/check your encodings between the `.tex` and `.bib` file.

Comment: I always trashed all aux files between my attempts to get something done. What I don't get is that there never has been a problem with my .lib file before updating MacTeX and biblatex and it works fine with every other style and compiler... I have no idea what to do.
and what do you mean by third? thanks for your help

Comment: Can you create a minimal example for others to test?  (By 'third', I just meant the third thing to check was what encodings are being used in teh `.tex` and `.bib` files.  `biblatex` has a `bibencoding` option in case you are using a special/different `inputenc` setting.  It probably is not relevant to your problem, but might be something to check.)  Another thing to sort out is that you have compatible `biblatex`  and `biber` versions; the documentation of each should specify which version of the other they require.

Comment: ok. thanks again for your help, I might just figured it out: I use zotero for reference management and export to bibtex via zotero. However, when you have a unified author field in zotero that contains capital letters, e.g. for an institution like: UNESCO, then zotero exports it using 3 (!!) {{{UNESCO}}} - which is too much for biber, as it seems. And this was causing the serious issues. Once I deleted one of the brackets it worked fine. I still have thousands of junk characters - but that's no prob. prblem was, biber only pointed me to the end of the document looking for a missing "}"...